# NPM install Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, npm, npm-install, cypress

At my company, there is an auto signed ssl certificate. So they're some npm packages that cannot be installed because of it.

I already add `strict-ssl=false` in `.npmrc` or `--strict-ssl=false` command args.

It works for some packages but some doesn't seems to take in charge this option.

For exemple, I tried to install *Cypress* :

**Command :**

`npm i cypress --save-dev --strict-ssl=false`

**Error logs :**

```
> cypress@3.4.0 postinstall /Users/mchoraine/Documents/Workplace/SAMSE/rechercheproduit/rechercheproduit-front/node_modules/cypress
> node index.js --exec install

Installing Cypress (version: 3.4.0)

 ✖  Downloading Cypress    
   → Cypress Version: 3.4.0
    Unzipping Cypress      
    Finishing Installation 
The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Please check network connectivity and try again:

----------

URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/3.4.0?platform=darwin&arch=x64
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

----------

Platform: darwin (18.6.0)
Cypress Version: 3.4.0
```

Problem seems to occur only for packages with `postinstall`

The smartest things would be to change the SSL certificate but unfortunately it can't be done.

So are you aware of an alternative to bypass certificat verification on npm postinstall ?

Thanks in advance for your proposal.

Comment: I get the same issue on `PhantomJS`

Comment: does this help?: http://blog.justintoo.com/2017/01/26/npm-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain/

Comment: i had this issue myself today. i work remotely on a company vpn, and it is responding slowly today. but, in the moments when it is responding faster i am not getting this error

Comment: oh. do you know? i just signed off the vpn for a second and the dependencies installed immediately

Comment: Ironically for me this same error (self signed certificate in certificate chain) occurred in cmd, but not in VS Code. I'm using a corporate proxy. Not sure why!

Answer (score 17):

Get a copy of your company's certificate, then set the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environmental variable to point to it before you run the npm commnand:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=path/to/certificate.crt
```

The post-install script is a separate node program, so the npm flag doesn't affect it.

Credit goes to "zerdos" who posted this solution on a related GitHub issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1401#issuecomment-393591520

Answer (score 3):

For me the following solution worked.

> OS - windows 10
>
> Terminal - git bash

Run these commands before installing cypress.

```
setx HTTP_PROXY <your company proxy url>
setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS <path to cerm.pem file>
```

These will be set as environment variables in your system for any future use.
You can always get rid of them anytime if you do not need them.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11.=>

I downloaded the binary file on from cypress cdn to my downloads folder and ran this in terminal

```
$env:CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY="C:\Users\YourName\Downloads\cypress.zip"
```

```
npm install cypress
```