# npm install electron failed with self-signed certificate in certificate chain error

Tags: electron, npm-install

I am trying to install electron on a corporate laptop (with strong security setting). I use the following command:

npm install electron

but have encountered the following error:

```
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 275ms
npm info run electron@23.1.2 postinstall node_modules/electron node install.js
npm info run electron@23.1.2 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
npm verb stack Error: command failed
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:53:27)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm verb pkgid electron@23.1.2
npm verb cwd C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm verb node v18.14.2
npm verb npm  v9.6.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\node_modules\electron
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! RequestError: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
npm ERR!     at origin.emit (C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
npm ERR!     at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12)
npm verb exit 1
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1677864834438
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:build 1677864913854
npm verb unfinished npm timer build 1677864913855
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:deps 1677864913856
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1677864914036
npm verb unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/electron 1677864914037
npm verb code 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T17_33_53_492Z-debug-0.log
```

Please note that before coming here, I have tried to set the strict-ssl to false, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Would really appreciate it if someone can give me some advice on what to do or where to look.

I have tried the solution in
[NPM install Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158587/npm-install-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

including downloading a certificate from chrome and add it to system environment.

For the full log, here it is:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.6.0
2 info using node@v18.14.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 3ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\zengw\.npmrc Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 15ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 15ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 8ms
.....
372 timing reifyNode:node_modules/cacheable-lookup Completed in 20478ms
373 timing reifyNode:node_modules/detect-node Completed in 20828ms
374 timing reifyNode:node_modules/extract-zip Completed in 21219ms
375 timing reifyNode:node_modules/json-buffer Completed in 21236ms
376 timing reifyNode:node_modules/get-stream Completed in 21380ms
377 timing reifyNode:node_modules/pump Completed in 22207ms
378 timing reifyNode:node_modules/graceful-fs Completed in 22359ms
379 timing reifyNode:node_modules/progress Completed in 22696ms
380 timing reifyNode:node_modules/es6-error Completed in 22881ms
381 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@sindresorhus/is Completed in 22941ms
382 timing reifyNode:node_modules/debug Completed in 23209ms
383 timing reifyNode:node_modules/semver Completed in 23221ms
384 timing reifyNode:node_modules/semver-compare Completed in 23579ms
385 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fd-slicer Completed in 23855ms
386 timing reifyNode:node_modules/define-properties Completed in 23976ms
387 timing reifyNode:node_modules/has-property-descriptors Completed in 24085ms
388 timing reifyNode:node_modules/json-stringify-safe Completed in 24154ms
389 timing reifyNode:node_modules/get-intrinsic Completed in 24538ms
390 timing reifyNode:node_modules/object-keys Completed in 25566ms
391 timing reifyNode:node_modules/function-bind Completed in 26121ms
392 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sprintf-js Completed in 26385ms
393 timing reifyNode:node_modules/sumchecker Completed in 26618ms
394 timing reifyNode:node_modules/has-symbols Completed in 26921ms
395 timing reifyNode:node_modules/http2-wrapper Completed in 27048ms
396 timing reifyNode:node_modules/boolean Completed in 28104ms
397 timing reifyNode:node_modules/globalthis Completed in 28182ms
398 timing reifyNode:node_modules/electron Completed in 28225ms
399 timing reifyNode:node_modules/type-fest Completed in 30404ms
400 timing reifyNode:node_modules/roarr Completed in 31271ms
401 timing reifyNode:node_modules/fs-extra Completed in 35670ms
402 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@electron/get Completed in 35676ms
403 timing reifyNode:node_modules/got Completed in 35775ms
404 timing reifyNode:node_modules/global-agent/node_modules/semver Completed in 37269ms
405 timing reifyNode:node_modules/global-agent Completed in 38795ms
406 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@types/node Completed in 39287ms
407 timing reify:unpack Completed in 39291ms
408 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
409 timing build:queue Completed in 4ms
410 timing build:link:node_modules/semver Completed in 154ms
411 timing build:link:node_modules/electron Completed in 156ms
412 timing build:link:node_modules/global-agent/node_modules/semver Completed in 157ms
413 timing build:link:node_modules/extract-zip Completed in 174ms
414 timing build:link Completed in 175ms
415 info run electron@23.1.2 postinstall node_modules/electron node install.js
416 info run electron@23.1.2 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
417 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 11648ms
418 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
419 timing command:install Completed in 93197ms
420 verbose stack Error: command failed
420 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:53:27)
420 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
420 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
420 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
421 verbose pkgid electron@23.1.2
422 verbose cwd C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron
423 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
424 verbose node v18.14.2
425 verbose npm  v9.6.0
426 error code 1
427 error path C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\node_modules\electron
428 error command failed
429 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
430 error RequestError: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
430 error     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:970:111)
430 error     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
430 error     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
430 error     at origin.emit (C:\Users\zengw\Desktop\GUI\electron\node_modules\@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:43:20)
430 error     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)
430 error     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
430 error     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
430 error     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
430 error     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
430 error     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
430 error     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
430 error     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
430 error     at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12)
431 verbose exit 1
432 timing npm Completed in 94179ms
433 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1677864834438
434 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1677864913854
435 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1677864913855
436 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1677864913856
437 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1677864914036
438 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/electron 1677864914037
439 verbose code 1
440 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
440 error     C:\Users\zengw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T17_33_53_492Z-debug-0.log
```